# How to do encryption based on key and salt in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, cryptojs

My Current work requires me to use this api. Now this api for getting auth token requires me to create a hashcode which is the encryption of a particular formatted string.This encryption uses salt and key. The sample code they gave is in java as below :

```
    try
    {
        byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
```

Now We are currently using Nodejs v8.9.0. I have worked with crypto before but can not comprehend the java code above.

Comment: _crypto_ provides the methods [`pbkdf2`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest_callback) and [`createCipheriv`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options). Try this and if you get stuck, edit the question, post your NodeJS code and a description of the problem. By the way, _crypto_ and _CryptoJS_ are two different libraries: [_crypto_](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto) is a NodeJS library, [_CryptoJS_](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/) is a JavaScript library.

Comment: Also could you provide sample input and expected output. This will help to understand if code we write generate similar output using nodeJS crypto library or any other